# In Sinatra, how do I make a multi-page pop-under form which stays on the same page as you fill it out?

Tags: javascript, ruby, forms, sinatra

I've made a form that appears in a pop-under window, but I can't figure out how to make it multi-step.

Here's my code:

1) `main.rb` file:

```
[
    'rubygems',
    'sinatra',
    'sequel'
].each{|g| require g}

DB = Sequel.sqlite('database.sqlite')

DB.create_table? :data_table do 
    primary_key :id
    varchar :img_path
    varchar :form1_name
    varchar :form2_option
end


before do 
    @img_path = nil
    @form1_name = nil
    @form2_option = nil
end

get '/?' do
    erb :index
end

post '/form2' do 
    user_img = params['user_img']
    @img_path = './public/images/uploads/' + user_img[:filename]

    File.open(@img_path,'wb'){|f| f.write(user_img[:tempfile].read)}# Copying the upload file to the server directory

    @form1_name = params['form1_name'] # !!!DATAPOINT!!!
end
```

2) `layout.erb` file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Multi-page form test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"> <!-- jQuery UI CSS -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script> <!-- jQuery UI -->
    <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <%= yield %>
</body>
```

3) `index.erb` file

```
<button id="upload_form_opener" type="button">Click here to upload</button>
<div id="upload_form_container" title="Form container title">
    <form action="form2" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <img id="upload_preview" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;" />
        <input id="upload_image" accept="image/*" type="file" name="user_img" onchange="PreviewImage();" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // This JavaScript snipppet is for previewing the image upload
            function PreviewImage() {
                var oFReader = new FileReader();
                oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("upload_image").files[0]);

                oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
                    document.getElementById("upload_preview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
                    // document.getElementById("upload_image").disabled = true
                }; // DONE: function (oFREvent)
            }; // DONE: function PreviewImage()
        </script>
        <p>Name <input type="text" name="form1_name" /></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Next" />
    </form>
</div>
```

4) `script.js`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var uFormContainer = $('#upload_form_container');

    // This snippet is for opening the pop-under form
    uFormContainer.dialog({autoOpen: false});
        $('#upload_form_opener').click(function(){
            uFormContainer.dialog('open');
    });
});
```

5) I want the second step of the form to look like this...

```
<form action="form2" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <p>Some other text field <input type="text" name="form2_option" /></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Next" />
</form>
```

...but I don't want to leave the page (which is '/', as far as Sinatra is concerned). Is this possible in Sinatra?

Comment: which webserv have you use? .. also try ajax requests for the page to load a html code into existed one, use, for example, jquery http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

Comment: I'm testing it locally right now.

Comment: Of course I meant locally, which webserver do you use locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to implement this:

1. Save some cookie or session, which step is now, and depends on that yield different forms. After submitting write next step id into session and redirect to root_url.
2. Use ajax to send form and render next step's form.
3. You can even not really send form, but just switch to next, just hidding previous fields with javascript and show next step's fields. After submitting all parameters will be sent.

Comment: I think I know enough to do #3, but not much about #1 or #2. How secure is each one?

Comment: all of them are same safety, but with #3 you can be pretty much sure in data consistancy